# Ubuntu Command line email sending

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I am trying to send an email to myself.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils` followed by

```
mail -s "This is the subject" --append=FROM:myemail@gmail.com
```

Then i get:

```
To:
Cc:
...
```

I enter the info in the To and Cc spaces followed by pressing enter. But, then it just gives me empty space. I click enter and it just keeps giving me new lines. Then I click ctrl^C twice and it kills the email. I just want to send it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Control-d to end it. Please see this Source https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail.

Comment: This did end it thank you, but sadly I did not receive my email :/ I'll accept your answer when I can seeing that I do believe it answers my question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add a relay host if you have one if the /etc/postfix/main.cf file